# Add one project to another as a submodule

Tags: ios, swift, git, git-submodules

I have `Project A` with `UITabBarController`. And I have `Project B` with one view controller with functionality.
I want to add `Project B` into `Project A` as a submodule using git. And then when I will add something to `Project B` I can fetch it from `Project A`.

But is there a way to use view controller from `Project B` in storyboard of `Project A`?

I have found this manual about git submodules:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Have added `Project B` as a submodule, then in storyboard of `Project A` created new view controller, set its class to class name from `Project B` and selected its module. Then when I run the application I've got an error `Unknown class _TtC9Submodule23SubModuleViewController in Interface Builder file.`

Can someone explain if it can work like this or what should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Project A is an app. But Project B is a static library or a dynamic one? Static libraries do not support ViewControllers inside them.

Comment: @MiguelIsla Project B is a second project that contains for now only one view controller which I want to add to a tab in Project A

Answer (score 0):

You've got two things going on - one is using the git repository with submodules and second is pulling the submodule code into Xcode.

Check with Finder to make sure that your file is created in the appropriate submodule folder after you've run:

```
git submodule init
```

to initialize your local configuration file, and

```
git submodule update
```

to fetch all the data from that project (you should check the messages for appropriate commit listed). If that is ok, then from finder drag and drop the files into your file list in xCode making sure that "copy items if needed" is not checked and "add to target" is correctly checked.

[image]

You'll be able to use the UITabBarController class and code you've created but still need to create it in the Main.storyboard and you need to be careful of any references to other views you had in project A if you do a copy and paste (It is possible that this is where your error is coming from).

And you can consider doing this via xib's or pods. Here is a straight up example of what you are trying to do with frameworks:

https://www.tapglue.com/blog/ios-frameworks-storyboards-swift/
https://github.com/tapglue/elements-ios

and with xib's

https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d